# Filebeat - shipping and processing configuration files in format key=value

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I'm using Filebeat to send logs to Logstash and from there to ElasticSearch.

I want to send also configuration files but I would like to decode it and convert it to json or to any other format that will let me run aggregation queries based on the configuration keys and values.

My file :

```
key1=val1
key2=val2
key3=val3
```

In Kibana, I would like to do some aggregation based on key1 for example..

Is there any processor like decode_json or decode_csv that I can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mecanism to parse this dataflow must be managed on logstash side, not on filebeat which must keep a minimal footprint on the host.

So in consideration of this point, you have to set the filter in the logstash configuration file which must looks like this :

```
filter{
  kv{}
}
```

For more details looks the official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html).

Comment: processors like decode_json should also be set in logstash and not on filebeat ?

Comment: I guess, you could seen the codec side in input of logstash : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/codec-plugins.html for have something that approach of decode_json function of filebeat

Comment: It worked , thank you ! What pattern u suggest to use in filebeat in order to ship all the configuration file as one event ? if the format is foo=bar